# java.io.FileNotFoundException while accessing from S3 bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, s3-bucket

I am doing a small POC in AWS. I trying to read a csv file from S3 bucket and displaying in the CloudWatch log files . Everything is going fine but while accessing the file getting java.io.FileNotFoundException

**Coding**

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, Report> {

Region AWS_REGION = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);

public Report handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Report statusReport = new Report();
    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

    logger.log("Lambda Function Started");
    logger.log("I am inside lambda function");
    Helper helper = new Helper();

    try {
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function2");
        S3EventNotificationRecord record = s3event.getRecords().get(0);
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function3");
        String srcBucket = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function4");
        // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
        String srcKey = record.getS3().getObject().getKey().replace('+', ' ');
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function5");
        srcKey = URLDecoder.decode(srcKey, "UTF-8");
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function6");

        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function7");
        S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(srcBucket, srcKey));
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function8");
        statusReport.setFileSize(s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength());
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function9");

        logger.log("S3 Event Received: " + srcBucket + "/" + srcKey);
        logger.log("I am inside lambda function10");

        File file = new File(srcBucket+"/"+srcKey);
        try {
            Scanner readData =new Scanner(file);
            while(readData.hasNext()) {
                String data = readData.next();
                logger.log("I am inside lambda function data ;;got it");
                //System.out.println("data"+data);
            }
            readData.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**CloudWatch Log file output**

[image]

**CloudWatch Log Errors**

I am inside lambda function

I am inside lambda function2

I am inside lambda function3

I am inside lambda function4

I am inside lambda function5

I am inside lambda function6

I am inside lambda function7

I am inside lambda function8

I am inside lambda function9

S3 Event Received: readfilefromcsvfile/def_nhtsa_crash_test.csv

I am inside lambda function10

java.io.FileNotFoundException:

readfilefromcsvfile/def_nhtsa_crash_test.csv (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: readfilefromcsvfile/def_nhtsa_crash_test.csv (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

If we will look into the log output it is telling that no such file, but I have kept it in S3 bucket. Can anyone tell me how to access S3 file in java ? or What is the path name I should give while accessing the S3 bucket file ?

Comment: Call `getObjectContent` of S3Object

Comment: Can you add you error as text to the question? This makes it easier to read for people who don't have 4k screens to zoom into the image, without having the switch between an tab containing your image and a tab containing your code

Comment: Java does not understand `s3://` URI. As such, you can't use `File` class to read a file from S3.

Comment: Thanks  @Ferrbig and Trinopoty, User7  for your quick response , I have kept the log files in the question.

Comment: Can I get the path from getObjectContent @user7

Comment: You need not worry about path here as the file is not there locally. getObjectContent would give you an inputStream

Comment: Can you give some idea  how to implement @user7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create a File instance here.  You can simply work on the S3 InputStream.

```
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(srcBucket, srcKey));
....
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s3Object.getObjectContent());
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Comment: Wow @user7 awesomw bro issue solved  thank you so much.